# Is there a way to generate Angular Modal Dialog with jhipster?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I would like to know if there is a way to generate modal dialog, selection dialog with jhipster cli? By the way what can we generate exactly with jhipster only new entities?

Comment: Second part of your question is not clear. Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhipster will generate CRUD related User interface elements like Grids, Input forms and of course some modals too. But only in a generic way and will not generate a specific component like Dialog or Form

Once you generate a Jhipster application, add a new entity to it using JDL, then you will be able to see some components generated which you might be able to reuse